# Which editor is used to open man pages in macOS? Is it even an editor?

Tags: macos, manpage

I am using macOS Sierra(unfortunately), and for example when I typed `man curl` to see what the `-LSso` flag does, it opens the man page in a editor which resembles vim slightly. I know its not Vim since it doesn't have :syntax on and you can't use :wq and so on.
The heading of the page says `man(less)`.

---

I can't find what editor this might be and I'm learning vim and emacs configurations. Or maybe it's just a man page and no editor is used?

Comment: It is not an editor, it is a viewer called `less`. Use `man less` to learn more about it.

Comment: You may find it easier to right-click and see the manpage in a separate yellow window that stays open. For example, if you start typing a `mv` command and want to check its options, right-click on the word `mv` and then select to view the manpage.

Comment: @DYZ yes it seems to be a viewer.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Can't right click and see the man page in macos Sierra in Iterm. Which OS and terminal are you using?

Comment: That's because you are using iTerm rather than the Apple-supplied Terminal.

Comment: The main commands are `space`=page forwards, `b`=page backwards, `G`=go to end, `1G`=go to start, `/string`=find string,`n`=find next occurrence of string,`q`=quit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Less is a program similar to more (1), but which allows backward movement in the file as well as forward movement.  Also, less does not have to read the entire input file before starting, so with large
       input files it starts up faster than text editors like vi (1).  **Less uses termcap** (or terminfo on some systems), so it can run on a variety of terminals.  There is even  limited  support  for  hardcopy
       terminals.  (On a hardcopy terminal, lines which should be printed at the top of the screen are prefixed with a caret.)

**Commands are based on both more and vi.**  Commands may be preceded by a decimal number, called N in the descriptions below.  The number is used by some commands, as indicated.

-- Copied from less man page

Comment: Ha, you got it from the man page on `less`. `Termcap` is just the thing I was looking for between the lines of the question. Thanks!